# Simulink - charge battery if SOC <20%

Tags: matlab, if-statement, simulink

what I need is some control logic that will start charging battery when SOC goes below 20% and stops at 80%. And it will start charging again when it hits 20%.
Is there some block which could do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I used relay block that does exactly what I want.